# Android dependency compatibility on adding admob package

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, admob

I'm adding admob in existing application which gives compatibility error in existing packages

existing packages

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.1'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
```

}

If i add admob package like below

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
```

it gives error on

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

stating that "must use the exact same version specification", I don't know how to know the compatible admob version for existing dependencies. I have searched for it but no helpful resource found.
can anyone say what is the correct admob dependency to use with these dependencies and how to know that?

and one more,

```
final NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) this.dialog.findViewById(R.id.adView3);
                **adView.loadAd(new AdLoader.Builder().build());**
                adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        super.onAdLoaded();
                        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

line `adView.loadAd(new AdLoader.Builder().build());` gives error that Builder(Context, String) in Builder can not be applied to Builder()

my import for this

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder;
```

How to fix this issue. If this second issue not related with my first problem then let me know i will post this as separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Google dependencies should be same version . if you do not do this this error will occur. Do one thing :

Change the version of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
```

TO

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
```

**And then add admob dependecy** :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
```

For Fixing the RecyclerView Error Please Replace This

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

To this :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v13:23.1.0'
```

And Also change this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

to This

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v13:23.1.0'
```

Reason behind this is you can not use v7 and v13 togather either you can use v7 or v13 . using both togather will genarate version compatibality error.

Comment: yes, that fix error on play-service, what is for compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'. and also can you tell how to find out the version

Comment: check your version for android design and support library for fixing recyclerview error